# What is the purpose of the website zuowen8.com, which contains student essays?

Tags: resources, learning

I have stumbled upon the following website: http://www.zuowen8.com/.

It seems to contain a daily-updated listing of school students' essays, categorized into groups.

I figured out it would be good language practice. However, I would like to ask more able Chinese speakers about the website - I trust that a language user would be able to grasp things after a modest glance.

- What is the purpose of the website? E.g.:

  - are the essays uploaded by students? Are they error-free?
  - is this meant to be a student resource, or a system to prevent plagiarism in essays?
- What does the website's catchphrase (让写作成为一种习惯) mean? My guess is: Let writing become (something of) a habit. (is 一种 a quantifier here?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about the Chinese language but about a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called 作文吧。

> What is the purpose of the website? E.g.:
>   are the essays uploaded by students? Are they error-free?
>   is this meant to be a student resource, or a system to prevent plagiarism in essays?

I think this website is for primary school/secondary school/high school students. The purpose is to provide some good examples to show how to write a good article/essay.

It's a kind of student resource, and usually, make it easy to plagiarize. Not sure if it's bug-free. But it's "high-grade" in exam.

> What does the website's catchphrase (让写作成为一种习惯) mean? My guess is: Let writing become (something of) a habit. (is 一种 a quantifier here?)

It's a slogan. Yes It's "Let writing become a habit".